# How to get process file name with non-elevated rights?

Tags: c#, windows-7, visual-studio-2005

I want to enumerate all processes on the machine, checking if `Process.MainModule.FileName` matches a specific path. With non-elevated rights on Windows 7, `Process.MainModule.FileName` throws a access denied exception.

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, to access processes that you do not have PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION permission, administrator privilege is required

You have full access to processes in the same user context, as well as the process handle returned by CreateProcess.

Comment: QueryFullProcessImageName requires only PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, but is only available for Vista and 7. So the possibility is there to get this information without elevated rights. But i need a function for XP.